# REST API call or database script

Tags: mysql, rest

Can you help me in weighing the below possible options to do a one-time batch insert for 2 million dataset?

Is it recommendable to have 2 million REST API calls to perform single inserts or a database script to run in few batches? This is for one-time, and I would like to weigh the pros and cons with this approach.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

Doing this as a database script will certainly be orders of magnitude faster than via a REST API, especially if the scripts are properly optimized.

The only reason I *might* use an API for something like this would be if you intend to do it frequently or you already have the API and just don't care how long it takes.